# I want buttons which change the screen to another screen on canvas

Tags: android, view, canvas, surfaceview

I already had buttons on my original app but now I created an image on canvas in Android and have combined the two together, however I cannot view the buttons on the page but can only see the image on the page. These buttons were designed to move to different pages. Does anyone know how this can be done. I have also used extend Activity instead of View/SurfaceView is that ok or will that be causing the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: how about some code? Show us your xml layout and how you are trying to use the buttons and image on the page

Comment: hi there mate can i send you my app on email, if u dont mind?

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

Comment: sorry that was a strand of my code in relative layout

Comment: no, don't send email. Post your code here.

Comment: I did above...im not sure how a button can be made which allows me to change screen...do i have to draw it in canvas and then place the onTouch method or can I use the normal java code and place code into the .java file and XML because I have already done the code but it does not show the buttons as they are showing on the GraphicalLayout but when I run the AVD there is no buttons on the page with Canvas?